# Image in Local Folder from WebView

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on a project where I need to access an image stored in the applications local folder from within a webview control.  When I try to use the ms-appdata:/// scheme it does not work.

I should also mention that I have no control over what content is loaded into the webview and so I must assume that there is no reference to base.js.

I guess my question is, is there any folder where I can store images on the device that I can access from within a webview.

I have tried:

```
ms-appdata:///local/
ms-appx-web:///local/
file://[path]
```

**Update**
This project is done using WinJS and Universal Apps.  So it is written entirely in JavaScript.

Comment: have you seen this article? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx

Comment: I have seen that article or others like it.  As I said, when I attempt to access the file via the ms-appdata:///local/ scheme it does not work.  Or any other scheme for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

I use this :

```
StorageFile file = await dir.GetFileAsync(name + ".jpg");
```

and I set this

```
"ms-appdata:///local/" + file.Name
```

in the "src" attribute of my image tag.

Comment: This is from C#, correct?  Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I tagged WinJS but never specifically mentioned that everything is JavaScript.  I will edit my question to make that more clear.  I appreciate the help though.

Comment: you can use the same in JavaScipt :
    storageFolder.getFileAsync(name).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );

see this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfileasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1